# Reseed id to 00000001 and when selecting it return as 00000001 and not as 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have reseed a database column to 00000001 but when I select it with C# it returns only the 1 without the zeros. Are leading zeros not allowed in ms sql?

Comment: The only column datatypes that support identity and hence reseeding are numeric types. None of them preserve leading zeros. You need to add them on at presentation time if desired

Comment: What is the datatype of this column?

Comment: it is the identity column, an INT

Comment: An `INT` column or numeric columns in general can't 've leading zeros. Unless you're using `N/VARCHAR(n)`.

Comment: I understand, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(id_field AS nvarchar), 8);
```

but as comments say auto numeric is an integer.

Comment: This actually won't work because `00000000` will be implicitly cast to integer leaving the OP where they started. `FORMAT(id_field,'D8')` would do it concisely.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f4e017878a102717ebacbc9d0c6a2fb

Comment: Thank you, @MartinSmith

Comment: 1) You should always specify the length of `N/VARCHAR`. 2) What's the need to cast to `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR(10)`?

Answer (score 1):

Numeric columns in general can't 've leading zeros and `INT` is one of them.
If you want to do so, you could use `RIGHT()` function as the following:

```
SELECT YourNumber, RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000', YourNumber), 8) DesiredResult
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1), (2), (100), (190)
) T(YourNumber);
```

Comment: Whats is "con't 've" short for?

Comment: Can't have @DaleK